# Writing delta tables to datalake using directory level SAS user delegation token in PySpark

Tags: azure, authentication, pyspark, sas-token

I have created a user delegation SAS token at directory level with all relevant rights.

Using following configuration to setup spark environment.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.<mycontainer>.<mystorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net", sas_token)
```

shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I get above error. This user delegation SAS token has all rights(read, add, create, write, list, move, execute) for the directory. Anyone else faced this error and solution for this would be helpful

When I create a user delegation SAS token at container level, the above code works fine and I am able to write delta/parquet tables both.
But when I create user delegation SAS token at directory level, it gives me the highlighted error.

Comment: Hi @Mayank As a work around you can try using this

Comment: spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<Storage accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net","<Storage account ACCESS KEY>")
file_path = f"abfss://<Container>@<Storage accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/"

Comment: Hi DileeprajnarayanThumula,  Thanks for your response. Requirement is to use SAS tokens and hence, was wondering what changes in spark config are required to make directory level token work, Thanks

Comment: Please check if this helps

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/interactive-data-wrangling-with-apache-spark-azure-ml.md#interactive-data-wrangling-with-apache-spark-in-azure-machine-learning

Comment: I am using the same configuration as suggested in Microsoft documentation.  Issue here is same configuration works for container level SAS token but does not work for directory level SAS token.  Do we need to configure spark in a different way while using directory level user delegation SAS token. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given correct SAS token for authentication I faced the same error when I have given incorrect SAS as shown below:

[image]

Make sure you followed below procedure to create user delegated SAS token at directory level:
Right click on the directory and select Generate SAS, select user delegation key and select permissions and generate SAS URL and copy it for authentication as shown below:

[image]

Use below code to write into parquet file:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.<containerName>.<storageAccountNmae>.blob.core.windows.net", "SASToken")
file_path = "<directory>/<file>"
df = df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("wasbs://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/" + file_path)
df.show()
```

The file will read successfully without any error:

[image]

Comment: Please note read functionality is not a concern. I face this issue while writing to datalake. 
Also, while reading I am facing difficulty reading a parquet table. A delta table or a flat csv works just fine.

Comment: I have edited the code to read parquet file.

Comment: Thanks for this response. However, rather having a single parquet file, could you Please try with a parquet table that is partitioned or may be have multiple part files. 
This is how my parquet table is stored as of now.

MY_ACCOUNT_STORAGE --> MY_CONTAINER --> DIRECTORY --> MY_PARQUET_TABLE_NAME --> ALL PART FILES WITHIN

If I give a token which has permission at this directory ( I am able to read successfully) but if I try to read using a token which has permission at MY_PARQUET_TABLE_NAME level, It fails to authenticate.

Thanks.